# How to dinamically create cookies in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a minesweeper game using Javascript and jQuery. You can see it here: https://sacredcandies.github.io/minesweeper/

My problem is that I want to implement a high-score system without using a database. I want to use cookies so that when the user restarts his browser the scores don't delete.

How can I create a function that dinamically add cookies? Something like and ArrayList of cookies. If this isn't possible what alternatives do I have?

Edit:
I ended up using local storage and Json to parse the array containing the scores. Thanks!

Comment: Personal opinion, `localStorage` is a little easier to work with than cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two potential approaches to the implementation of such score-storage system. One you mentioned already although with some inefficiencies. The other is the use of **localStorage**.

**Cookies Approach**

Cookies' purpose is mainly for server-side purposes. In this case you would not need an ArrayList of cookies but rather a single cookie called "**highScore**". This cookie would save the highScore and the comparison between current score and highScore would take place, of course, in your game.

**localStorage Approach**

LocalStorage could be considered a better approach with similar implementation. It has **significantly larger storage capabilities** in terms of bytes stored compared to cookies. This might not make a big difference for a simple **highScore** number but it gives you a lot of room and flexibility to add other attributes related to your game. It is intended for client-side only and the **highScore** won't be deleted unless you do it via JavaScript or manually.

Comment: A user running in incognito mode would also not be able to use localStorage, or it would not be persisted as expected.

Comment: @Taplar Correct, that is true indeed. There is no workaround as far as I know but localStorage is massively used by HTML5 games, therefore I would assume the "risk" or rather the "disadvantage" was duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 mostly used localStorage for this purpose.

Here is the example how you can use localStorage.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Local Storage</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>Final Score: <span id="result"></span></div>

<script>
// Store
localStorage.setItem("score", 890);

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("score");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```